# Вывод с двух таблиц на одну страницу

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Нужно вывести данные из разных таблиц на одну страницу.
При чем из одной таблицы все благополучно выводится. Из другой таблицы... никак не хочет.

Вот как я прописываю обращение к этим таблицам:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT img,title,links FROM slideshow");
$center = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT title,text,phone,adress FROM index");

/*Проверка*/
if ((!$result)&&(!$center))
{
echo "<br>Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору по e-mail: admin@admin.com<br><strong>Код ошибки: </strong>";
/*Останавливаем*/
exit (mysqli_error($link));
}

/*Есть ли в $result  и $center хоть одна строка*/
if ((mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)&&(mysqli_num_rows($center)>0))
{
$myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$info = $center->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
/*Если $result < 0 и $center < 0, то останавливаем*/
else
{
echo "<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена, таблица пустая, или в ней нет записей, соответствующих запросу.</p>";
exit();
}
?>
```

Потом в нужных местах из таблицы index вывожу данные обычным способом:

```
<?php printf("%s",$info['title']);?>
```

Обе таблицы не пустые, в них есть нужные данные.

Ругается на строку:

```
$info = $center->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Пишет или вот так

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysali_fetch_assoc() in Z:\home\localhost\www\ves\blocks\center.php on line 45
> ...или вот так: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in Z:\home\localhost\www\ves\blocks\center.php on line 42
> Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена, таблица пустая, или в ней нет записей, соответствующих запросу.

Если указывать:

```
if ((!$result) || (!$center))
```

то выходит ошибка:

> "Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору по e-mail: admin@ves.ves 
> Код ошибки: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index' at line 1".

P.S.: вообще стыдно... мне кажется, что все так примитивно у меня построено, а я даже в этом разобраться не могу...

Comment: Попробуйте так:
    "SELECT `title`,`text`,`phone`,`adress` FROM `index`"

Comment: Да, поставила грависы и все получилось. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово `index` является зарезервированным в MySQL. Поэтому во втором запросе ошибка - вместо имени таблицы MySQL встречает зарезервированное слово. Если переименовать таблицу - не вариант, то нужно взять слово index в одинарные обратные кавычки (backtick): `index`.

[Документация по резервированным словам MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: вообще все поля и таблицы обязательно экранировать кавычками в  каждой выборке SELECT `title`,`text`,`phone`,`adress` FROM `index` тогда вы точно опрделеляете что это поля таблицы и таблица а не какие-то выражения или резервированные слова.

Comment: > An identifier __may be quoted or
> unquoted__. If an identifier contains
> special characters or is a reserved
> word, you must quote it whenever you
> refer to it. The set of alphanumeric
> characters from the current character
> set, “_”, and “$” are not special.

Следовательно, заявление об __обязательном__ экранировании всех неключевых слов неверно.

[http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html][1]

  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html